# TypeScript Mapped Type - Convert type properties to instances of type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert an object full of class constructors to a mapped object with properties that are functions that return an instance.

For example:

```
// From an external auto-generated utility:
class FooClient { getData() {}}
class BarClient { getData() {}}

export const Clients = {
    FooClient,
    BarClient
}
```

Which can be consumed:

```
import { Clients } from './somemodule';

type ClientTypes = typeof Clients;

function getFooData(c: ClientTypes) {
  const fooClient = new c.FooClient();
  return fooClient.getData();
}
```

What I am shooting for is to replace the classes / constructors with factory functions:

```
type Factories = {
  [Property in keyof ClientTypes as `use${Property}`]: () => ClientTypes[Property]
}

function getFooData(f: Factories) {
  const fooClient = new (f.useFooClient());  // <-- use function returns the original constructor type
  return fooClient.getData();
}
```

My question is, how can I change the return type on the mapped type such that it does not return a constructor, but rather, I want it to return the value as if the constructor had been called.

For example:

```
function getFooData(f: Factories) {
  const fooClient = f.useFooClient();  // <-- returns an instance instead
  return fooClient.getData();
}
```

Is there some kind of keyword that can indicate that I want my function to return an instance of a type instead of the type itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, however, when you were typing the return type of `use_` you returned the class type.  However, you need to do a little bit more work to make it act as a regular function that returns a class instead of a constructor.  You can do this by creating a new function that returns `InstanceType<ClientTypes[Property]>`.

```
class FooClient { getData() {}}
class BarClient { getData() {}}

export const Clients = {
    FooClient,
    BarClient
}

type ClientTypes = typeof Clients;

type Factories = {
  [Property in keyof ClientTypes as `use${Property}`]: () => InstanceType<ClientTypes[Property]>
}


function getFooData(f: Factories) {
  const fooClient = f.useFooClient();
  return fooClient.getData();
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28DCICWBTAdgF2gb2gHN1sARMbMACgEp8BfegKFEhgCEwAnFDHfIiXKVaDZk3QAPAA7wuuYPEwRcvLNhgBefE2h64iNTgA0u-Zx5p1TcdgCe09NCPYAKg-Rbo9x-ABmzlY4EADcTEw+TrBgwNhyGF54ZgDaAApc8I7ydtComNAA1uh2-oF8bh4wkNAABgCuEOgAJHhFJQEu7o4Q9DUAugBc0KKaAHzQAJLKlJjA6F3oADydlWkZWfZ9ozbhTH51s9ioSoLYCPDC1H5D0bHxnnRJeorT0H6GQbjafgB0DegWFy0MJ6LgkOpcfLvZCfH7EMgUag0ML0IA)

If you wanted to include constructor parameters in this callback, then add a rest parameter to the function type with the type of `ConstructorParameters<ClientTypes[Property]>`.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Only one small issue in the provided sample, which is the duplicate use of `keyof` which causes the `useBarClient()` call to return `FooClient | BarClient`. I will make a suggested edit which fixes this.